# Update User Meta Via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, meta

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I have an ajax function which runs every few seconds and it basically checks 2 database tables and if they do not match then update one of the database tables to match the other database table, but for some reason it doesn't update the database table. How do I edit the function so I can achieve this?

Here are the functions inolved:

```
function tb_update_old_followers($user_id) {

    $followers = tb_get_follower_count($user_id);

    $old_followers = tb_get_old_follower_count($user_id);

    $response['new_new_followers'] = $followers;

    $response['old_new_followers'] = $old_followers;

    $response = json_encode( $response );

    echo $response;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_tb_old_followed_by_count', $followers + 1);

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_tb_update_old_followers' , 'tb_update_old_followers');

function tb_get_follower_count( $user_id = null ) {

if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
}

$followed_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_tb_followed_by_count', true );

$count = 0;

if ( $followed_count ) {
    $count = $followed_count;
}

return (int) apply_filters( 'tb_get_follower_count', $count, $user_id );
}


function tb_get_old_follower_count( $user_id = null ) {

if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
}

$old_followed_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_tb_old_followed_by_count', true );

$old_count = 0;

if ( $old_followed_count ) {
    $old_count = $old_followed_count;
}

return (int) apply_filters( 'tb_get_old_follower_count', $old_count, $user_id );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ok one moment..

Comment: @Luca That's edited now if you want to have a look... Thanks

Comment: What does "echo $response;" return?

Comment: @ElvinHaci it returns the count for `$response['new_new_followers'] = $followers;` and `$response['old_new_followers'] = $old_followers;` but it doesn't perform any action other than that.

Comment: ok i have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple.  You haven't defined user_id inside tb_update_old_followers() function. Just do it and it would work.

```
function tb_update_old_followers() {
    $user_id=get_current_user_id();

    $followers = tb_get_follower_count($user_id);

    $old_followers = tb_get_old_follower_count($user_id);

    $response['new_new_followers'] = $followers;

    $response['old_new_followers'] = $old_followers;

    $response = json_encode( $response );

    echo $response;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_tb_old_followed_by_count', $followers + 1);
    die();
}
```